# How do I suppress Yes/No Prompt when Saving digitally signed Mail in a format that is not secure?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, prompt, save-as

I wrote VBA to save an email as a text file.

For digitally signed emails it prompts me if I want to save the file in a format that is not secure (yes or no to continue). I want to suppress this warning.

I tried the following:

```
With Application
     .EnableEvents = False
     .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
m.SaveAs savePath, olTXT 
With Application
     .EnableEvents = True
     .ScreenUpdating = ture
End With
```

And

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
m.SaveAs savePath, olTXT 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

They both do not work (I get a compile error). How do I turn off these alerts in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are for Word or Excel.  Outlook does not have the equivalent functionality.  The best you can do is use the SendKeys method to simulate clicking the Yes or No buttons: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The tool you need is a free add-in by MAPILab called Advanced Security for Outlook. It presents a logical and smoothly integrated extension to Outlook security system, which enables to put an end to irritating warnings without compromising on your safety.
https://www.mapilab.com/outlook/security/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override the "digitally signed" flag, see [How set PR_SECURITY_FLAGS MAPI properties in outlook add-in (New Web Add-In, Office JS + Manifest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448926/how-set-pr-security-flags-mapi-properties-in-outlook-add-in-new-web-add-in-off) Of course, this should only be done in a copy of the mail. See

```
 Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
 Set OutlookApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set namespace = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myMailItem = namespace.OpenSharedItem("...") ' Path to msg file
 myMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS 0
 myMailItem.SaveAs savePath, olRTF
```