# How set PR_SECURITY_FLAGS MAPI properties in outlook add-in (New Web Add-In, Office JS + Manifest)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

How to set emails PR_SECURITY_FLAGS (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003) property with any of the below values.

NONE | 0x0000 | Message has no security
ENCRYPTED | 0x0001 | Message is encrypted
SIGNED | 0x0002 | Message is signed
SIGNED | ENCRYPTED | 0x0003 | Message is signed and encrypted

Used Custom properties , but didnt work out.
I am working on Outlook latest web add-in (Office.Js + Manifest)
Please help me here

Comment: Are you working with a classic COM Add-in? or the new Web Add-in? Also what scenario are you trying to solve? Are you trying to encrypt a message? Just read this property?

Comment: I am working on new Web Add-in (Office JS + Manifest), creating a encrypt message..@OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot encrypt emails from the office.js api at this time. Feature requests can be made at: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Feature requests from uservoice are considered during the planning process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it also not possible with EWS or Graph API ? @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

Use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` and specify the the DASL name (`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"`)

Answer (score 0):

For [Outlook Web Add-Ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview), we do not support setting the `PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` property. We have a [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page where we track feature requests. Please add a request there. Feature requests on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it also not possible with EWS or Graph API ?

Comment: That is not an Outlook Add-Ins-specific question, so please create a new post and tag exchangewebservices and outlook-restapi to get the best eyes/responses.

Comment: Please vote here in User voce ::https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/41194219-set-pr-security-flags-mapi-properties-in-outlook-a